# Specific Keystroke for batch

Tags: batch-file, keystroke

I am trying to find out how to make batch wait for a specific keystroke. I don't want any of those pause>nul echo Press Enter to continue... None of that stuff, I would like it so that way once you press a key (eg. a) then it will go to :Test, if you press another key then it won't react what so ever. And I looked at the first page result, and went to the links on Google.

Comment: Are you really working on DOS, the OS from the 1980s, or do you mean the Windows command prompt instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the solution to your problem is the **CHOICE** command. This will allow you to set a key, have the batch script wait for that key to be pressed, then continue. It also avoids any cryptic pausing or loops in the script.

Keep in mind that the `choice` command has a few syntax's

- `/C` - Specifies the list of choices to be created.
- `/N` - Hides the list of choices in the prompt.
- `/CS`- Enables case-sensitive choices to be selected.
- `/T` - The number of seconds to pause before a default choice is made.
- `/D`  - Specifies the default choice after timeout seconds.
- `/M` - Specifies the message to be displayed before the prompt.

For the sake of your usage, the following script can be used. Its also important to note you can have multiple keys act as your *specific keystroke* by doing ex: `12345` for `SET KEY=`

```
@ECHO OFF

::Change this key to what ever you wish.
SET KEY=N

:Start
cls
echo Press %KEY% to continue...
choice /c %KEY% /n /cs
if %errorlevel%==1 goto Continue

:Continue
cls
echo Hello World!
pause.
```